# How to make sure an inline jQuery script gets executed last of everything within a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inline

I have a problem when trying to style some html of mine dynamically. The setup is as follows:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="gridster">

  <ul>
    [...]
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
      <div data-id="someid" class="scrollable" data-view="List" data-unordered="true" data-title="someTitle"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".scrollable").css("overflow", "hidden");
  $(".scrollable").children(".content").css("height", "100%");
  $(".scrollable").children(".content").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
  $(".scrollable").children(".content").css("margin-right", "-50px");
  $(".scrollable").children(".content").css("padding-right", "50px");
});
</script>
```

I am using [Dashing/Smashing](http://dashing.io/) with [Dashing Icinga](https://github.com/dnsmichi/dashing-icinga2) to create Dashboards. Inside the `<div>` block there are several other `<div>` blocks created at runtime by backend scripts, generating the actual widget-contents.

As you can see from the script snippet in the end, I am trying to adjust both, the already existing div's as well as one of its children-to-be div's CSS at runtime, I just need to make sure this code gets executed **AFTER** the children of my original `div` have been loaded. How can I manage to do so?

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: can you please add whole code? AS `.contents` is not added in `scrollable LI`

Comment: Thats what I tried to explain and need to fix. `<div class="content" [...]></div>` gets added by the `Dashing` framework at runtime, so it is not there in the html-file which gets loaded when the page is requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly do with CSS. You don't need to do with javascript.

```
<style>
.scrollable {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable .content {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Comment: ...I literally tried solving this on my own for three hours and never got the idea that if I already introduced an extra class I might as well just add extra css... Thank you.